# DeWalt circular saw stopped working, probably need to repair motor, can anyone confirm?

Tags: repair, electric-motor, circular-saw

Okay, so I got a a circular saw from the family for Christmas for my burgeoning woodworking hobby, and I've been using it a light amount. It went out the other day while cutting some 1x4. I had a little kicking while sawing through, but not too bad. Suddenly, the saw whirs down and dies. I think the battery is dead, so I switch. No good. I test with my drill, the batteries are both fine.

I've disassembled it fully and put it back together, verifying that there's no blockages, I can manually turn the spindle. Additionally, I've tested the circuit, and there's the ~18v getting from the battery to the spade connectors on the motor, but when I pull the trigger nothing happens. No sound, no motion, nothing.

The only thing in the saw I couldn't identify is some kind of square plate that rests abutting the motor housing. My suspicion is that it's a temperature sensor?

Anyone got suggestions to figure out what I need to do?
It's a DCS391 model circular saw.

Comment: You got it for Christmas (2015, presumably?) - warranty repair. Of course, you may have voided that via **disassembly...**???

Comment: Warranty repair-or-exchange would indeedbe the right answer. Given@Ecnerwal's observation, I'd first try returning it go the store; they're less likely to notice tampering, and more likely to just give you a new unit off the shelf rather than a refurb.

Comment: Stores only replace the first 30 days unless you bought the extended warranty.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not worth taking apart tools such as a handheld circular saw or drill. There is not much in the way of user-serviceable parts, and doing so may void any warranty you have with the manufacturer.

First, I recommend looking up if there are any "consumable" parts such as fuses which are user-serviceable. This may be a quick and easy fix.

Your next step should be finding an [authorized DeWalt service center](http://www.dewalt.com/Find-Service-Center.aspx) that has the specialized tools, parts, and training to repair the tool. The major tool companies tend to have company-owned or authorized third-party repair centers in major metropolitan centers in the U.S. at the very least. They can inspect the tool and tell you if repair makes sense: it may cost more to repair the tool than to replace it. Being this new, however, it is likely covered by a factory warranty that will cover a significant portion of the cost.

Answer (score 0):

Many electric tools have a 'thermal cutoff' . This is like a fuse in the line of the stator. You used to be able to buy them and swap by clipping out the old one and crimping in a new one. - - Look at this article for more info < https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_cutoff>